# Covariance vs. contravariance with respect to class inheritance

Tags: class, inheritance, terminology, covariance, contravariance

What is the meaning of the concepts 'covariance' and 'contravariance'?

Given 2 classes, **Animal** and **Elephant** (which inherits from **Animal**), my understanding is that you would get a run-time errors if you try and put an Elephant into an array of Animals, and this happens because Elephant is "bigger" (more specific) than Animal.  But could you place an Animal into an array of Elephant, seeing how Elephant is guaranteed to contain the Animal properties?

Comment: Useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have it backwards.  You can add an Elephant to an Animal array because it *is an* Animal, and it's guaranteed to have all of the methods an Animal is required to have.  You can't add an Animal to an Elephant array because it does **not** have all of the methods that an Elephant is required to have.

The Wikipedia article on [covariance and contravariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) has a good explanation of this:

> Within the type system of a programming language, an operator from types to types is covariant if it preserves the ordering, ≤, of types, which orders types from more specific ones to more generic ones; it is contravariant if it reverses this ordering. If neither of these apply, the operator is invariant. These terms come from category theory.

Also, you said that type Elephant was "bigger", and this is not the case.  Type Animal is "bigger" in the sense that it includes more specific types, such as Elephant, Giraffe, and Lion.

Comment: Ah that makes sense so would you would say an Elephant is covariant to an animal but an animal is contravariant to an elephant?

Comment: It depends on what you're doing with the types.  The methods of Elephant need to return the same or narrower type as Animal's methods (they could return Animal or Elephant, if the Animal method returns Animal).  That would be called covariant.

Comment: But the method parameters of Elephant's methods need to be the same or wider than Animal's methods.  This is contravariance.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this overview of covariance and contravariance in C# 4.0 and see if that helps:

http://blogs.msdn.com/charlie/archive/2008/10/27/linq-farm-covariance-and-contravariance-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should try reading pages 45-49 of [Introducing .NET 4.0 With Visual Studio 2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143022455X) which deals with this exact example. It even has some nice photos of elephants.

The main point to take out is, to do this

```
var things = new List<IThing<IContent>> { new ConcreteThing() }
```

with:

```
public class ConcreteThing : IThing<ConcreteContent>
{

}
```

you need the "out" in the interface definition, which will allow more specific forms to be set, but anything read out of IThing must be guaranteed to be the more general type.

```
public interface IThing<out T> where T : IContent
{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
public interface IGoOut<out T>
{
    T Func();
}
public interface IComeIn<in T>
{
    void Action(T obj);
}
public class GoOutClass<T>:IGoOut<T>
{
    public T Func()
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

public class ComeInClass<T> : IComeIn<T>
{
    public void Action(T obj) {  }
}

==========================================================
object obj = null;
//Covariance Example [Array +  IEnumerable<T> +  IEnumerator<T>  +  IInterface<Out T>  +  Func<T>]
object[] array = (string[]) obj;
IEnumerable<object> enumerable = (IEnumerable<string>) obj;
IEnumerator<object> enumerator = (IEnumerator<string>)obj;
IGoOut<object> goOut = (GoOutClass<string>)obj;
Func<object> func = (Func<string>)obj;


//Contravariance Example[IInterface<in T>]
IComeIn<string> comeIn = (ComeInClass<object>) obj;
```