# Type casting Collections using Conversion Operators

Tags: c#, operators, explicit, operator-keyword

The below code gives me User-defined conversion must convert to or from enclosing type, while snippet #2 doesn't...  It seems that [a user-defined conversion routine must convert to or from the class that contains the routine.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x7fay24(VS.80).aspx)

What are my alternatives?  Explicit operator as extension method?  Anything else?

```
public static explicit operator ObservableCollection<ViewModel>(ObservableCollection<Model> modelCollection)
{
    var viewModelCollection = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>();

    foreach (var model in modelCollection)
    {
        viewModelCollection.Add(new ViewModel() { Model = model });
    }

    return viewModelCollection;
}
```

Snippet #2

```
public static explicit operator ViewModel(Model model)
{
    return new ViewModel() {Model = model};
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. You've run into the covariance/contravariance problem with collections in .net 2-3.5. This has been "fixed" in .net 4. Read this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx, then these questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962629/contravariance-explained http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272428/covariance-vs-contravariance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724919/understanding-covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-4-0. Hope this helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting a generic collection to base type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539287/casting-a-generic-collection-to-base-type)

Comment: @Worrier: Thanks for your response.  ViewModel/Model do not have relationships between them.  Not sure if this is that issue.  I was simply looking for a way to cast the way 'digEmAll' has shown below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to convert the collection using:

```
var viewModelCollection = new ObservableCollection<ViewModel>(modelCollection.Cast<ViewModel>());
```

If you like exstensions you could define something like (to avoid the new in the previous code):

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableCollection<T>(this IEnumerable<T> coll)
{
   return new ObservableCollection<T>(coll);
}
```

Or maybe, to do everything in one shot:

```
public static ObservableCollection<TNew> CastObservable<TNew,TOld>(this ObservableCollection<TOld> originalColl)
{
   return new ObservableCollection<TNew>(originalColl.Cast<TNew>());
}
```

Obviously all the previous codes, will work if you have defined the snippet #2

Answer (score 0):

Your first code snippet should work as a udc on the observablecollection class.

Comment: I guess ObservableCollection is not his own code, but maybe this one --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=VS.95%29.aspx